# How to see logs when deploying to Heroku from Github?

Tags: heroku, github

I have a nodejs repo  on github and I have it connected with Heroku with the auto dpeloy option. Then when I push to master it will be deploy to Heroku server also. My question is how can I see the logs of my application? I can only find the build logs.

If it is a Heroku repo then I can do a `Heroku logs` but now I only have my git repo.

Thanks!

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have probably enabled GitHub integration on your Heroku app. You still have a Heroku app right - that's what you enabled the GitHub integration on.  If your app's name is `foo-bar-123` then `heroku logs -a foo-bar-123` should do it.

Answer (score 10):

Another method of viewing logs that might be more convenient is:

1. Go to Heroku app page (e.g. dashboard.heroku.com/apps/myAppName)
2. Click on "more" at the top right of the page
3. Click on "view logs" at the top of this menu

This enables you to view the app's logs on the Heroku online GUI, without needing to install the Heroku CLI.

[image: diagram of steps to view logs online]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean build output (not regular running logs), they are in the Heroku Dashboard: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#where-can-i-view-build-output although I'd like to have a way to see them command line too.

Comment: There's a plugin for this now: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds

`heroku builds:output -a appname`